# Runtime Error 1004 for a userform which is still there

Tags: excel, vba, userform

To simplify use of a spreadsheet and avoid anyone just adding or deleting rows as they wish (and therefore messing up the formulae) I have used a series of userforms. The first Userform gives the user the option to either 'Cancel', 'Delete Row', or 'Insert Row'.  Selecting 'Cancel' unloads the form, and selecting 'Delete Row' unloads the original form and shows another Userform - this allows the user to select the row number they want to delete, and pressing OK deletes it.  This all works fine.

The issue I have is with the 'Insert Row' button - this should unload the first Userform and show another userform.  This new 'Insert Row' Userform allows the user to input the row number after which the new row is to be inserted.  The user has the option to input further detail in various textboxes and comboboxes which will populate the new empty row - these include start and end dates.

I was having integer vs string issues with the option for manual input of the dates, so I opted to go with another 2 userforms, opened from the start and end dates which gave a calendar (select the date you want, press OK and the date is inserted in the relevant textbox in the 'Insert Row' userform).  I tested these all the way through to iron out the wrinkles, and everything seemed to be working.

I then opened the first userform from the command button on the spreadsheet,
 Selected 'Cancel' and 'Delete Row' to check they still worked, then selected 'Insert Row' and got 'Runt-time error '1004' Application-defined or object-defined error'.  When I went to debug, it highlights the line: *userform1.show*

The only thing I can think of that could be a problem (and the only significant change I've made) are the two calendars, which reference userform1.  I've carried out multiple searches, but haven't found anything which even looks like my problem - I just don't know what the issues are with having multi-layered userforms.  I've included some of the code by way of further explanation:

```
Private Sub InsertRowButton_Click()

  'unload the first userform when the user selects "Insert Row"

  Unload ModifyProjectUserForm1

  ''This line highlights as the problem

  UserForm1.Show

End Sub

'''the following subs are embedded in "UserForm1" (the one to Insert Row), allowing the user to select a date:

Private Sub InsertRowNumberStartDateCommandButton_Click()

  frmCalendar1.Show

End Sub

Private Sub InsertRowNumberEndDateCommandButton_Click()

  frmCalendar2.Show

End Sub

'''The following are the subs used to take the dates and place them in "UserForm1":

Private Sub StartDateCalendarOK_Click()

  On Error Resume Next

  UserForm1.InsertRowNumberStartDateTextBox.Value = frmCalendar1.Calendar1.Value

  Unload frmCalendar1

End Sub

Private Sub EndDateCalendarOK_Click()

  On Error Resume Next

  UserForm1.InsertRowNumberEndDateTextBox.Value = frmCalendar2.Calendar2.Value

  Unload frmCalendar2

End Sub
```

I expected the 'Insert Row' userform to open, allowing me to put a new row in, with associated data, and dates.  What I got was a runtime error, and I'm at a complete loss.

I don't know if I'm going down completely the wrong route, but I'm loathe to post my entire code, because there's a lot of it!

Can anyone help?

Comment: Is there a reason you want to destroy (unload) the form? Have you tried to use `Hide` instead?

Comment: Reading it now. Thanks

Comment: @MathieuGuindon - thanks for the recommendation, though I'm still at a loss!  I'm very much a beginner with vba, and everything I've put together so far has been mainly by trial and error, so I have no idea where to place the code you recommend within the code I have.  I'm just not sure if I can simply correct the code I have with what you recommend, or I have to start from scratch - I've tried multiple instances of your code where I think it should go, but keep getting exactly the same error code.  I know I'm a novice in here, but can anyone help?!